# Gerrit 3.2.3 with HTTP Basic/Digest authentication: Unable to Start service

Tags: apache2, basic-authentication, gerrit, digest-authentication

I am trying to install gerrit 3.2.3 with http authentication. I have the following configurations for gerrit in gerrit.config and apache2 in /etc/apache2/sites-enable/000-default.conf:

gerrit.conf:

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
        canonicalWebUrl = http://10.20.30.40:8444/
        serverId = ed568797-ae0c-4e44-a5ac-4a419df2349e
[container]
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.backend_factory=com.google.common.flogger.backend.log4j.Log4jBackendFactory#getInstance"
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.logging_context=com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContext#getInstance"
        user = gerrit
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
[index]
        type = lucene
[auth]
        type = HTTP
[receive]
        enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = mail.example.com
        smtpServerPort = 587
        smtpEncryption = TLS
        smtpUser = whoami
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:8081/
[cache]
        directory = cache
```

and the 000-default.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
Listen 8444
<VirtualHost *:8444>
  ServerName 10.20.30.40
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  <Location "/">
      AuthType Digest
      AuthName "realm"
      AuthDigestDomain /
      AuthDigestProvider file
      AuthUserFile /var/www/html/htpasswd

      # These 3 lines below for basic authentication:
      # AuthGroupFile /dev/null
      # AuthBasicProvider file
      # AuthUserFile '/home/stl/passwords'
      Require valid-user
  </Location>
  AllowEncodedSlashes On
  ProxyPass / http://10.20.30.40:8081/
</VirtualHost>

#vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
#vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The apache starts up without any problem with `sudo service apache2 start`.
However when I try to start gerrit (gerrit_site/bin/gerrit.sh start), I get the following error:

```
[2020-09-19T12:38:16.521-0400] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server : jetty-9.4.30.v20200611; built: 2020-06-11T12:34:51.929Z; git: 271836e4c1f4612f12b7bb13ef5a92a927634b0d; jvm 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~16.04-b01
[2020-09-19T12:38:16.574-0400] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.session : DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
[2020-09-19T12:38:16.574-0400] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.session : No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
[2020-09-19T12:38:16.576-0400] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.session : node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
[2020-09-19T12:38:16.662-0400] [main] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.gitiles.HttpModule : No /home/gerrit/gerrit_latest/etc/gitiles.config; assuming defaults
[2020-09-19T12:38:16.826-0400] [WorkQueue-1] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.deleteproject.fs.RepositoryCleanupTask : Cleaning up expired git repositories...
[2020-09-19T12:38:16.828-0400] [WorkQueue-1] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.deleteproject.fs.RepositoryCleanupTask : Cleaning up expired git repositories... Done
[2020-09-19T12:38:17.155-0400] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler : Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5eadc347{/,null,AVAILABLE}
[2020-09-19T12:38:17.157-0400] [main] ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start HTTP daemon
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.http.jetty.JettyServer$Lifecycle.start(JettyServer.java:105)
        at com.google.gerrit.lifecycle.LifecycleManager.start(LifecycleManager.java:95)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:362)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:268)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.AbstractProgram.main(AbstractProgram.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.invokeProgram(GerritLauncher.java:224)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.mainImpl(GerritLauncher.java:120)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.main(GerritLauncher.java:65)
        at Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8081
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.http.jetty.JettyServer$Lifecycle.start(JettyServer.java:91)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:220)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:345)
        ... 19 more
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Looks like the http daemon from gerrit is trying to access 8081, but its not able to.

Request your assistance in solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I had put an entry in ports.conf - Listen 8444. Removing that solved the issue. It appears that apache2 was blocking that port.